# add progress bar in minicart magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, mini-cart, free-shipping, template-override

I'm new to Magento, I have this module which adds progress bar in cart summary 
https://github.com/christophermallory/magento2-freeshipping-progress-bar, 
I want to add it to minicart

Comment: You just need to enable the module that's it. Read that documentation where placed in your given link.

Comment: The module add the progress in cart summary, i want it in minicart

Comment: To show this progressbar in the mini-cart, you can create a custom block that uses the ProgressBar  and adds it to the mini-cart template.

Comment: And how i do this?!

Comment: Check my answer try it

Answer (score 0):

||create a new module.

||Create a new template file that includes the progress bar
**(view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml)**

||create a file named **default.xml** in the directory **view/frontend/layout/**

||save this code in default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.minicart" template="Vendor_Module::cart/minicart.phtml" />
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Run after flush.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: What was the error

Comment: Nothing happened